# Making a hyperlink from a address

Tags: php, html

So i made a simple product ordering website.
When a customer wants to order a product he enters his details name, phone number and address.
And on the admin panel i receive all the details in clear text.

So i have a question, not sure if this is possible at all i am just a newbie.
I want that address part to convert from clear text to a hyperlink (on admin panel) which will lead to google maps website/app so that i can just press "Directions" after that and deliver it to the customer. I don't always want to do it manualy (copy paste).

example:

| Tommy Vercetti | Hawaii Shirt | +123 456789 | Vice City | **Ocean Drive 123** |

So when i press the "Ocean Drive 123" part i just want it to open the google maps app/website for me automatically.

Edit:

[Picture of order on admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdbNf.jpg)

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4lCg.jpg)

I probably didn't explain what i wanted to do correctly the first time.
On the second picture i want the $customer_address to work with the google maps url. So basicaly when i press the address it automatically opens google maps url and ads the $customer_address part.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Got the hyperlink going and just need the correct URL?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because i have no idea how to even do that. I just started out "programming". :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thank you for your help. I managed to do it by myself. Not the best looking code by any means but it's working.

```
<td><font color = "#87898a"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/<?php echo $customer_address; ?> " target="_blank"><?php echo $customer_address; ?></a></font></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the full address is: Ocean View 123, Hilo, HI, USA

```
<a href="https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Ocean+View+123,+Hilo,+HI,+USA>Ocean View 123</a>
```

just add + in places of all white spaces and it should work. See it here
[Ocean View 123](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Ocean+View+123,+Hilo,+HI,+USA)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the data using `rawurlencode()`.

```
<?php
$customeraddress = "Ocean Drive 123, Vice City";
$businessaddress = "123 business address lane, Vice City";

echo '<a href='https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/',rawurlencode($businessaddress),'/',rawurlencode($customeraddress), '">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some advanced techniques to build up a valid Google Maps URL, but the easiest one I can think of is construct a simple URL that concatenates your address to a predefined URL.

Notes

- uses a base URL of https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/start_address/end_address. Customize this to your needs
- URL encode the addresses https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding
- uses https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php to format some strings

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f584e44e1e9ca65f65f59fe70a1f41b4c416446

```
<?php

// The address you're starting from.
$origin = '125 Union St, Brooklyn, NY';

// The destination address you're going to. 
$destination = '500 King St S., Toronto';

// Google Maps URL which is made up of origin and destination. URL params are encoded. 
$url = sprintf('https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/%s/%s', urlencode($origin), urlencode($destination));

// Use target="_blank" so the link opens in a new tab. 
echo sprintf('<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', $url, $destination);

// Produces this URL
<a href="https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/125+Union+St%2C+Brooklyn%2C+NY/500+King+St+S.%2C+Toronto" target="_blank">500 King St S., Toronto</a>
```